# gtaphql-upload v4 POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, graphql, apollo

i am super confused, i think the problem is on the server setup,
also i downgraded graphql-upload to v13 to be able to import it with require syntax
i keep receiving POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys.
i tried almost everything, i have no idea what else to try...

[image: apollo sandbox]

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const { ApolloServer } = require('@apollo/server');
const { startStandaloneServer } = require('@apollo/server/standalone')
const { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } = require('@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer');
const { schema } = require('./schema.js');
const { resolvers } = require('./resolvers.js');
const {
  graphqlUploadExpress, // A Koa implementation is also exported.
} = require('graphql-upload');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const { json } = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const jwtmiddleware = require('./middleware/auth.js')
require('dotenv').config();
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress())

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

const start = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/SamichayUsers', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });
}

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  resolvers,
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
});

const startServer = async () => {
  await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 5552 },
    context: jwtmiddleware
  });

  app.use(
    '/graphql',
    cors(),
    json(),
  );

  app.listen(5551, () => {
    console.log('Connesso alla porta: 5551');
  });
}


start()
startServer();

module.exports = { app }
```